# An extremely mysterious integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{k \tan^{-1}(t)}{k^2 + t^2}\mathrm d t$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

> $$f(n) = \int_0^1 \frac{n \tan^{-1}(t)}{n^2 + t^2}\mathrm d t \tag{n > 2}$$

**Introduction:**
This is one of the most beautiful and mysterious integrals I've every encountered. It's very simple, but my conjectured closed form is one of the most bizzare I've ever seen.

**What I know:** 
All of the closed forms that Mathematica gives have the following form:

> $$\frac18 \big(\tan^{-1}(a_n)^2 - 4i \cot^{-1}(n) \log(b_n) + 
>    2 i \tan^{-1}(a_n) \log(b_n) - 2 (\text{Li}_2(c_n - id_n) + \text{Li}_2(c_n + id_n)- 
>       \text{Li}_2(\frac{1}{b_n}) \big{)}$$

Pretty ugly, I know. But the really amazing part is what comes next.

**The Conjecture:**

> $$a_n= \frac{\left.
>   \begin{cases}
>     2n & \text{n even}  \\
>     n & \text{n odd }
>   \end{cases}
>   \right\}}{\text{lcm}(n+1,n-1)} \\
> b_n=  \frac{\left.
>   \begin{cases}
>     n+1 & \text{n even}  \\
>     \frac{n+1}{2} & \text{n odd }
>   \end{cases}
>   \right\}}{\left.
>   \begin{cases}
>     \frac{n}{2} & \text{n even}  \\
>     n & \text{n odd }
>   \end{cases}
>   \right\} \\} \\
> c_n =  \frac{\text{(n-1) * largest prime factor of } n-1}{\text{largest odd divisor of } n^2 + 1}
> $$
>   And I have no idea what $d_n$ could be.

The conjecture holds for at least the first 20 values of n, as well as 20 other random higher values of n, and I think it's too simple to just be a coincidence. So, my questions are:

1. What is $d_n$?
2. How can I prove or disprove this conjecture?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It has occured to me that I may have gotten some of the equations wrong when copying them over from Mathematica. If you find an error, please edit and fix it or comment and I will, thanks :D

Comment: As soon as you know that $\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{2 i}\left(\log(x-i)-\log(x+i)\right)$ and that $\text{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^xdt\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}$ you should be able to resolve some of the mysteries you discovered :)

Answer (score 1):

*I'll give you an insight on how to solve the integral*

Start by

$$F(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(at)}{n^2 + t^2}\,dt$$

By differentiation

$$F'(a) = \int_0^1 \frac{t}{(n^2 + t^2)((at)^2+1)}\,dt = \frac{\log(1+a^2)+ \log \left( \frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)}{(-2 + 2 a^2 n^2)}$$

Integrate

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(t)}{n^2 + t^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+a^2)}{(an)^2-1}\,da+\frac{1}{2}\log \left( \frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)\int^1_0\frac{1}{(an)^2-1}\,da$$

Then second integral is easy

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}(t)}{n^2 + t^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+a^2)}{(an)^2-1}\,da-\frac{1}{2}\log \left( \frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\right)\frac{\tanh^{-1}(n)}{n}$$

Then you can use the following properties for the first integral

$$\int^t_0 \frac{\log(1+ax)}{1-x}\, dx = -\log(1-x)\log(1+a)- \text{Li}_2 \left( \frac{a}{a+1} \right) +\text{Li}_2 \left(\frac{a-ax}{a+1}\right)$$

$$ \int^t_0 \frac{\log(1+ax)}{1+x}\, dx  = - \text{Li}_2 \left( \frac{t}{t+1} \right) +\text{Li}_2 \left(\frac{t-ta}{t+1}\right)-\text{Li}_2(-at)$$

Note that

$$\frac{\log(1+a^2)}{(an)^2-1} = \frac{\log(1+ix)+\log(1-ix)}{(an-1)(an+1)}$$